# AndroidAnnotations and constructor injection

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-annotations

I'm going through androidannotations cookbook and I can't find way to inject dependencies to Bean via constructor.

Is it possible at all with this library? I have everything else up and running, but I just can't fix this single problem :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AndroidAnnotations [does not provide this feature currently](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/204). Setter injection maybe added in the next release.
Use field injection, if possible.